# UIview top constrained to safe area, but in viewDidLoad, the view has the wrong Y position

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload, safearealayoutguide

Vertically, my views:

Safe Area <- 40 -> Label

So in Interface Builder, iPhone 8, the `Label` has a Y coordinate of 60.  Because of the 40 top constraint, but also the safe area has a height of 20

At runtime, I also see the label has the Y coordinate of 60

However, when I set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()`, it looks like that safe area isn't factored in y et, because the `Label` has a Y coordinate of 40

I have tried calling `view.layoutSubviews()`, and the Label still doesn't move until some time after `viewDidLoad()`.

Is there any way to get the final Y coordinate (60) in my `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: `viewDidLoad`, as its name suggests, is when the views are loaded, not when they are laid out. They are laid out when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. Is there any reason why you want the label to be laid out correctly specifically in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following-up on this, the final positions of my views were set before `viewDidAppear`, so that's where I ended up doing my frame computations